# angularjs pagination: Unknown provider: ngTableParamsProvider

Tags: angularjs, pagination, ngtable

I want to implement the **pagination** in angular js.
I am new to angular js.

I get this error in browser:

Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/unpr?p0=ngTableParamsProvider%20%3C-%20ngTableParams%20%3C-%20allUsersCtrl

I have included these files at the HEAD section of layout view:

```
<!-- angular js--->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>angular/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>angular/js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <!-- flash msg -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>angular/js/angular-flash.js"></script>
    <!-- flash msg -->
     <!--loading bar-->
   <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>angular/js/loading-bar.min.js"></script>
   <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>angular/js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
   <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>angular/js/ng-table.min.js"></script>
    <!--loading bar-->

    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>angular/js/demo_angular.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>angular/js/app.js"></script>
```

**This is my table in partial html:**

```
 <table ng-table="tableParams"  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="table_all_users">
                                    <thead>
                                         <tr>
                                            <th width="20%"><input type="checkbox" name="chk_all" id="chk_all"  onchange="checkAll(this)" /> Select</th>
                                            <th width="15%">Sr. No.</th>
                                            <th width="35%"><a href="" ng-click="reverse=!reverse;order('username', reverse)">User Name</a></th>
                                            <th width="25%"><a href="" ng-click="reverse=!reverse;order('fname', reverse)">First Name</a></th>
                                            <th width="25%"><a href="" ng-click="reverse=!reverse;order('lname', reverse)">Last Name</a></th>
                                            <th width="15%"><a href="" ng-click="reverse=!reverse;order('mobile', reverse)">Mobile</a></th>
                                            <th width="15%"><a href="" ng-click="reverse=!reverse;order('email', reverse)">Email</a></th>
                                            <th width="15%">Action</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>

                                    <tbody ng-init="get_users()">
                                        <tr class="gradeX" ng-repeat="user in allUsers | filter:query">
                                          <td width="20%"><input type="checkbox" name="list[]" class="chk_all" value="" id="" onclick="uncheck_select_all(this);" /></td>
                                          <td width="15%">{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
                                          <td width="35%">{{ user.username }}</td>
                                          <td width="25%">{{ user.fname }}</td>
                                          <td width="25%">{{ user.lname }}</td>
                                          <td width="15%">{{ user.mobile }}</td>
                                          <td width="15%">{{ user.email }}</td>
                                          <td width="15%"><a title="Edit User" href="#/edit_user/{{user.user_id}}" ><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span></a> | <a title="Delete User"  id=""  style="cursor:pointer;"  ng-click="delete_user(user.user_id)" ><span class="fa fa-trash-o"></span></a></td>
                                        </tr>

                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

**This is the script.**

```
var angularControllers = angular.module('angularControllers', ['flash']);  

angularControllers.controller('allUsersCtrl', ['$scope','$http','$filter','Flash','ngTableParams', function($scope,$http,$filter,Flash,ngTableParams){
   $scope.get_users = function()
        {
            $http.get("../admin/users/angular_all_users").success(function(data)
            {
                $scope.allUsers = data;    
            });
        }
    //for sorting by table column
    var orderBy = $filter('orderBy');
    $scope.order = function(predicate, reverse) 
    {
        $scope.allUsers = orderBy($scope.allUsers, predicate, reverse);
    }
    //table pagination
     $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,            // show first page
        count: 10           // count per page
    }, {
        total: data.length, // length of data
        getData: function ($defer, params) {
            $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
        }
    })


}]);
```

When I am adding here as: **['flash','ngTable']**
still it gives error : *data is not defined*

Also after trying to implement pagination **my data is not going to display**, only header row is display.

**Please suggest me any solution or any link that will guid step by step for pagination**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My advice to you is always to initialize the ng-table in *$http.get*. It must be like:

```
    $http.get('../admin/users/angular_all_users').success(function (data) {
            $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,
                count: 10
            },
            {
              total: data.length,
              getData: function ($defer, params) {
       // use build-in angular filter for ordering
        var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                $filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()) : data;

        $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
    }
});
    });
```

With this "best practice" you will always avoid the problem that `data` with it's properties is undefined.

Don't forget to include `ngTable` in your module.

Hope this will push you forward.

Best regards!

Comment: If you are satisfied with answer, I will be thankfull for voting. This is one of ways how you can use the response directly in ng-table initialization. Thanks!

Comment: Do I need to replace $scope.allUsers = data;  by your code?

Comment: If I use your code(js code) how my view line will be? <tr class="gradeX" ng-repeat="user in allUsers | filter:query">

Comment: Solved. Pagination Done! Just 1 problem: I am printing 1 column as index that is Sr. No. 
So when I go to next page or second page, Sr.No. or index again start from 1. 
This is how I printed that: {{ $index + 1 }}

Comment: Always use _$data_ for binding in your _ng-repeat_ view. doesn't matter how your $scope for data is named in controller, because it's ng-table default stuff. Just read the whole documentation carefully, there are great stuff automized. I'm glad that I could help. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because you are trying to include a dependency called `ngTableParams` which I think is in the module called `ngTable` which you have not included.

When you include the module as well, you are getting data is undefined. This is because you are using `data` variable in line

```
total: data.length, // length of data
```

but you have not declared the variabled before usage. I think you missed that.

You can just check the line number in the error to determine what is the problem. Try putting breakpoints, so you can easily trace the issues.

Comment: You are right @Kop4lyf , he forget to include the injection in his module. I will try to make better organized and functional code in next answer.

Answer (score 1):

I also meet this error

```
/**
 * @ngdoc service
 * @name ngTableParams
 * @description Backwards compatible shim for lowercase 'n' in NgTableParams
 */
angular.module('ngTable').factory('ngTableParams', ['NgTableParams', function(NgTableParams) {
    return NgTableParams;
}]);
```

the above code can find in angular-ngtable.js, but I don't use this version, I success when I replace this, or change `ngtableParams` to uppercase (recommand).